# PHP web service for command line users

Tags: php, web-services

I have been given a task to write a web service to push data from sensors to the server database.

I have written a PHP webservice which takes some arguments in GET, process the data in it and stores the data in the database.

**Example**

```
http://www.example.com/pushDataService/index.php?arg1=<Data 1>&arg2=<Data 2>&arg3=<Data 3>
```

But our firmware programmer wants something that he can test on a command line.
Just like SMTP communication using telnet

**Example**

```
Telnet mail.example.com 25
EHLO mail.example.com
AUTH LOGIN
UserName encrypted in base 64
Password encrypted in base 64
MAIL FROM:<test@example.com>
RCPT TO:<test@domain.com>
DATA this is a test message.
```

Can I make the webservice work like this where he can do the handshaking process in command line and then each argument is sent individually and user get a response for each argument ?

Please help, I am new to PHP and have no idea of (web) service like this!

Thank you

**Edit:**
We are already using MQTT to push the data to the server but we need another server to push data which will work as a combination of SMTP mail server and MQTT protocol...
Will a SOAP web service do the job for me?

Comment: checkout http://php.net/cli

Comment: i don't think php will do the trick for that at least not alone, you should check out how to make a incoming tcp port on your server

Comment: i remember when i use to reprogram electricity meters that send data via 3G they always connected to a port and yes the use smtp similar to a mail maybe you can add a mail server and modify to the right format to get the data

Comment: Please learn what https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service is. The `web` part of the name implies http, not raw tcp as in your example.

Comment: @Gert do you have some example code to share here ?

Comment: how is the firmware setup does it push out data at certain intervals or do you have to request the data then it sends the data back? most devices works like this, it connects to the internet via gprs then connects to a server using protocol that is very similar to a mail server .each device have a different name but most use the same password. this normally get programmed in to them. then they send smtp data to server in telnet format. and sorry no i have never written server side code for the devices

Comment: We already have a protocol where server initiates a communication (send some command) and the sensor returns the data. Now we want to 'Push' the data to the server without server asking for it. We also use MQTT but we need another service which will work like a combination of SMTP mail and MQTT...

Comment: then use php mail script check for mail read the mail and get the data then write it into a data base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `http://www.example.com/pushDataService/index.php?arg1=<Data 1>&arg2=<Data 2>&arg3=<Data 3>` request can be done *Just like SMTP communication using telnet* as following:

```
Telnet www.example.com 80
GET /pushDataService/index.php?arg1=<Data 1>&arg2=<Data 2>&arg3=<Data 3> HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
<CR>
<CR>
```

Pushing data with GET requests is not the best idea. PUT or POST requests would be more suitable. First of all it is not idempotent and should never be cached, and what is more important - it is way more flexible in data format and size. The POST request sending json data may look like

```
Telnet www.example.com 80
POST /pushDataService/index.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 57

{"arg1":"<Data 1>", "arg2":"<Data 2>", "arg3":"<Data 3>"}
```

Comment: I know the web service can be accessed just like this, but as I mentioned in the question, I need response after handshaking and after sending each argument. Say, when I type `Telnet www.example.com 80` and press enter, I should get a response saying `connection established` Send argument 1 and so on....

Comment: As I commented before this kind of communication is not a **web** service any more, yet can be done with [raw sockets](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php), see [example of the socket server](http://php.net/manual/en/sockets.examples.php). There are 2001 challenges to solve if you following this route, starting from defining your own communication protocol, ending with maintenance of long-running php scripts, and socket management. PHP is hardly the best tool for the job.